# Where can i find the actual location of the pthread.h file in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am working on something and I needed to dig inside the implementation of the pthread_create() function of **POSIX threads in Linux**.

Where can I find the actual location of the **pthread.h** file or the actual code implementation of **pthread_create()** in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to find any file on most linux systems is to use the `locate` command

```
$ locate pthread.h
```

That being said, the file on my Ubuntu system is located at: `/usr/include/pthread.h`

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=pthread_create%28%29&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code) to find the implementation of pthread_create()